# In React, how do I render a stateless component that is passed in as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, components, render, prop

I want to render a component based on whetehr a user is logged in

```
              <PrivateRoute
                    authed={isAuthenticated} path="/unapproved-list/"
                    component={UnapprovedList}
              />
```

The PrivateRoute component is set up like so

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({component, authed, ...rest}) => {
  console.log("in private route, authed: " + authed);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => authed === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
    />
  )
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

However, when authentication is true, this line

```
Component {...props} />
```

is resulting in the below error

```
TypeError: instance.render is not a function
finishClassComponent
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17160
  17157 | } else {
  17158 |   {
  17159 |     setIsRendering(true);
> 17160 |     nextChildren = instance.render();
        | ^
  17161 | 
  17162 |     if ( workInProgress.mode & StrictMode) {
  17163 |       instance.render();
```

Not sure how to structure my private route to properly render the component.  I would prefer not to change the component structure, which is currently like the below

```
const UnapprovedList = () => {
    const [unapprovedCoops, setUnapprovedCoops] = React.useState([]);   ...
    return (
        <>
            {loadErrors && (
              <strong className="form__error-message">
                {JSON.stringify(loadErrors)}
              </strong>
            )}

            {loadingCoopData && <strong>Loading unapproved coops...</strong>}

            <RenderCoopList link={"/approve-coop/"} searchResults={unapprovedCoops}  columnOneText={"Unapproved Entities"} columnTwoText={"Review"} />
        </>
    )
}

export default UnapprovedList;
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the `component` you're passing to `PrivateRoute`. That's the actual component you're trying to render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<Component {...props} />` line refers to the `Component` class imported from the React instead of the `component` prop because of the first letter upper vs lower case.

Try the following:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: WrappedComponent, authed, ...rest }) => {
  console.log("in private route, authed: " + authed);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => authed === true
        ? <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
    />
  )
}
```